# clicking button using executescript in protractor - POM

Tags: javascript, protractor, end-to-end

I have to click a button and since it is not clicking directly, i am using the below code and it is working.

```
var create = element(by.css('button[title="Add Master Obligation"]'))
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[1].click();", create, create);
```

I want to put the same for page object model in protractor. So, i have added like this.
page.ts:

```
var mo = function () {

    this.createbutton = function () { 
        var create = element(by.css('button[title="Add Master Obligation"]'))
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[1].click();", create, create);   
    }
```

If I call this in my spec, like below

```
var mo = require("../page/mo.ts")

    it('create  master obligation', function () {
        browser.sleep(10000);
mo.createbutton;
    })
```

it is not clicking the button. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, *you are not calling the function* - replace `mo.createbutton` with `mo.createbutton()`.

Comment: thanks alecxe it is working..i m so dumb...

Comment: alecxe, add it as a answer so that i can accept it

Comment: No problem. To follow the SO rules, we should close it as "no reproducible anymore", I've close-voted. Thanks and glad it's working.