# How to choose unique element in two same model?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I am trying to select unique element but the problem is there is 2 model with no unique mode, and id is dynamic.
[its the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM6g2.png)
test spec

```
it('Rental Car should work ', function() {

let rentalCar = new Hotel();
rentalCar.operator.sendKeys('Eurocar');
rentalCar.carClass.selectValue('M');
rentalCar.pickupTime.sendKeys('12');
rentalCar.DropOfTime.sendKeys('13');
//rentalCar.cancelable.check();
rentalCar.clientAmount.sendKeys('120');
rentalCar.supplierAmount.sendKeys('12');
rentalCar.pickupLocation.sendKeys('berlin');
rentalCar.selectpickOption.click();
browser.sleep(2000);
rentalCar.dropLocation.sendKeys('Han');
browser.sleep(2000);
rentalCar.selectDropOption.click();
browser.sleep(2000);
rentalCar.save();
```

})

i tried to add first() and last() at the end of page object but its getting error "TypeError: $(...).first is not a function "

```
class Hotel {
```

constructor() {

```
this.operator = element(by.model('$ctrl.item.operator'));
this.carClass = new MdSelect('$ctrl.item.class');
this.pickupTime = element(by.model('$ctrl.item.pickup_time'));
this.DropOfTime = element(by.model('$ctrl.item.return_time'));
//this.cancelable = new MdCheckBox('$ctrl.item.isFlex');
this.clientAmount = element(by.model('$ctrl.item.traveler_item_data[0].line_items[0].gross_amount'));
this.supplierAmount =element(by.model('$ctrl.lineItem.supplier_gross_amount'));
this.pickupLocation = $('md-autocomplete md-autocomplete-wrap md-input-container [aria-label="Pickup location"]');
this.selectpickOption = $('md-virtual-repeat-container md-autocomplete-parent-scope');
this.dropLocation = $('md-autocomplete md-autocomplete-wrap md-input-container [aria-label="Drop-off location"]');
this.selectDropOption = $$('.md-virtual-repeat-container .md-autocomplete-parent-scope '); }
```

help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`first()` and `last()` are available on `ElementArrayFinder`. Your error says that you are trying to use `first()` on `ElementFinder`.

Comment: yes, i am trying to use it, but even though i don't use first() and last() ,then rentalCar.pickupLocation.sendKeys('berlin');
rentalCar.selectpickOption.click(); it passed but 
rentalCar.dropLocation.sendKeys('Han');
browser.sleep(2000);
rentalCar.selectDropOption.click(); it failed and the reason is element is same, i don't know how to differentiate both

Comment: Try this: `this.selectDropOption = $('.md-virtual-repeat-container:nth-of-type(1) .md-autocomplete-parent-scope`

Comment: nope ,it doesn't work either 
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .md-virtual-repeat-container:nth-of-type(1) .md-autocomplete-parent-scope)

Comment: when i tried in developer tool document.querySelectorAll('md-virtual-repeat-container')[2].querySelector('md-autocomplete-parent-scope')
it worked but when i tried to apply on test getting error, how i can use browser.executescript for that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131882/clicking-button-using-executescript-in-protractor-pom

Answer (score 0):

if there are two same elements, you can use

```
element.all(by.model('model')).get(0);
```

Depending upon the index, you can use get(0), get(1).

Comment: i have tried that too the error is same  ;(    TypeError: $(...).get is not a function

Comment: You need to resolve the promise before calling `get` . https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder